# Adding arbitrary details in pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Is it possible in `pytest` to record arbitrary data from test executions.

For example:

```
import random
class TestSomeStuff:

   def test_something(self):
       r1 = random.random()
       r2 = random.random()

       ## I'd like to do something which could make these
       #  values accessible later, so that they could be
       #  put into a report
       self.r1 = r1
       self.r2 = r2
       ###

       assert r1 < r2
```

I'd like to save details about the test, which could be put into a report. I'd like the report to be able to include these details, regardless of whether or not the test failed.

Can `pytest` be made to report arbitrary details about a test?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you would like to use that data later? Because a simple answer would be to save this intermediary files into a known location (using for example json) and then read back and added to your report.

Comment: I think that's what I'll end up doing. Or make a fixture with a dictionary attribute that'll get filled, then stored to disk in the finalization code. This seems pretty hackish though, so I'm wondering if there is a natural way to do it within the `pytest` framework.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities within pytest, but to suggest something more appropriate I would need to know more details of what you are trying to accomplish exactly. :) Anyway, take a look at [pytest hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html), there is a lot of room for customization in there (for example, `pytest_runtest_logreport`).

Comment: I am wondering the same. I need to save some object filled with data during pytest execution run, and then reuse it when making report (Ideally I want to access it within pytest_runtest_logreport(report) hook function). Is this possible with non-hackish solution (and ideally without serialization)?